# Joint linear least squares, how to solve?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, least-squares

Say I have the following $$\min_{\bf x_1,x_2}\left\{\|{\bf Ax_1 - Bx_2}\|_2^2 + \text{other terms linear in } \bf x_1,x_2\right\}$$
for matrices $\bf A,B$ and vectors $\bf x_1,x_2$

How to arrange to solve it using linear methods like a linear equation system or linear least squares?

Comment: What's the other terms linear in $x_1, x_2$?

Comment: @JirapatSamranvedhya  :They can be written in the same way with matrices $A_k, B_k$ minus maybe various constant vectors. $$\|A_k x_1 - B_k x_2 - d_k\|_2^2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\| Ax-b\|_2^2  + \| Cx-d\|_2^2 $ is equal to $\| Dx-e\|_2^2$ where $D = \begin{pmatrix}A\\B\end{pmatrix}$ and $e = \begin{pmatrix}b\\d\end{pmatrix}$.

$\| A_1x_1 + A_2 x_2-b\|_2^2$ can be written as  $\| Ax-b\|_2^2$ where $A = \begin{pmatrix}A_1 & A_2\end{pmatrix}$ and $x = \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Yes you are right and that can also be helpful at least the second part of the question when we have more terms. But it does not answer what to do if we have different x vectors $x_1,x_2$ under the same norm and need to put them together somehow.

Comment: Tha'ts just changing the notation. I've added that

Comment: Yes it's probably quite trivial for you I suppose. Nice answer.